# “Ten bucks says…" or "Ten bucks say…"? Which is correct?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

In the movie Avengers I, when the Cap said,“At this point, I doubt anything would surprise me.” Then the director Fury answered,**“Ten bucks says you’re wrong."**

I understand that Fury was betting ten bucks that the cap was wrong. My questions are:

1) 'Ten bucks' is a plural, why use '**says**' instead of '**say**'?

2) It's not the first time I heard this expression and it seems most time people use 'says'; so is it a fixed phrase ? Or some kind of abbreviation for some sentence? If so, could anyone help to show me the complete version? Thanks a lot.